# Template conditional logic is not working

Tags: jquery-templates

here is some problem in using conditional logic for checkbox 
i try checked=true or false but it is not working,there for i choose for conditional logic in template,I want checked="checked" for matching condition

```
    <table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Department Name</th>
      <th>Test Name</th>
      <th>Sub Test Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {#foreach $T.d as post}
    <tr>
      <td>{$T.post.Dep_Name}</td>
      <td>{$T.post.Test_Name}</td>
      <td>{$T.post.Sub_Test_Name}</td>

      <td>
      {{if $T.post.Status==Checked}}
      <input id="chkResult" type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
        {{/if}}
        <input id="chkResult" type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td><input id="Button2" type="button" value="button" /></td>

    </tr>
    {#/for}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using something similar to this

```
 <input id="chkBox" type="checkbox" 
       {{if account.checkImage}} checked="checked"{{/if}} />
```

you need to modify the logic in {{if}} like

```
 {{if $T.post.Status== "Checked" }}
```

Guess the condition you are checking for is a string.
Let me know if you are still facing any issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working like this

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chk${FeeSettingDetailID}" {{if IsRefundable}} checked{{/if}} />
```